# Using custom classes as properties of another class' definition

Tags: python

While I have some Python experience, I'm coming from a mainly Java background for object-oriented programming. Thus, I'm used to declaring variable types.

For simplicity, say I'm creating classes A and B, both of which have their own functions. I'd like to use A as one of the class properties for B. Therefore, upon creating A and B, I can call the methods for object B, and object A which is part of B. I've included a sample code below.

While this code works, I am concerned that it may not be the proper way to do so. In Java, I would be able to declare the variable type for the input to class B and I would move on. However, I haven't been able to figure out the proper implementation for this in Python.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,aa):
        self.aa = aa

    def fun(self):
        print(self.aa)

class B:
    def __init__(self,a): # a is an A Object
        self.a = a

    def fun(self):
        print(self.a.aa + 1)

a = A(1)
b = B(a)
b.fun()
b.a.fun()
```

- Having the two classes/objects separate help make the code more readable as the classes directly correspond to the physical machinery the program is meant to control. This is why I'm not using parent/child classes.
- Putting everything within one all-encompassing class isn't feasible as classes A and B are not being initialized at the same time. This is also why I cannot use a subclass.
- Aside from the program crashing if the wrong object type is passed into B, I am also not getting the auto-complete suggestions in VS Code for the properties and methods of class A when referencing them within class B (i.e. typing "self.a.aa"). This is a significant inconvenience as there are a significant number of properties and functions in both classes.

Comment: There seem to be several questions here. Is this about static vs. dynamic typing? If so, Python has a gradual typing interface and several good type checkers (mypy being the one I tend to use). But you also say a bunch of things about VS Code and about when to subclass, so I'm not entirely clear on *which* question you want answered.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ah...I didn't know about static vs dynamic typing. mypy does seem to be what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround to get appropriate autocomplete suggestions is to use [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).  You need to import the `typing` module then alter the `init` function for `B` to tell it `a` is expected to be an `A`:

```py
import typing
...
class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        ...
```

VS code will then understand that if `b` is a `B` then `b.a` is an `A` and offer to autocomplete `b.a`'s instance variables and methods.

The type hints are just that - hints - and using something of the wrong type in the `B` constructor won't cause an error at compile time.  If you want to handle the case when the wrong kind of argument is supplied, you can use [`isinstance(a, A)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test if `a` is an `A`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I knew about isinstance, but type hinting solves the IDE issues and should leave the code clear for others to read.